# How do I clone a git repository to a new project?

Tags: git

For example, I want to use some framework that's located on Github. Is there a way to clone a repository without the `.git` structure? That way I can add new a remote url and push to my own repository appropriately?

**Edit**

The purpose of this is so that I can take a framework off from Github and put it into my own brand new repository without importing any git data from the framework's repository (like git logs). I know you can clone and remove the appropriate data or you could just download a tarball using Github's tool, but I'm just wondering if there's any easier way to do it such as like a `git clone`, preferably a single command.

Comment: According your comment on my removed question I don't understand your question. Why don't you want .git structure? Why don't you want to use fork? Provide some more details.

Comment: I want to import the repository as my own "clean" repository. Kind of like starting off from scratch with a framework that you use. Obviously from this, you don't want to import the git logs that it contains. That way, your starting off with a brand new git repository with the framework you want to use. I'm just asking if there's an easier way to do a `git clone` rather than doing it myself with rm's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want just the repo latest content, without any git information, then the tarball is the best solution, and can be done with a single command line:

```
curl -L https://github.com/username/reponame/tarball/master | tar zx
```

or

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/username/reponame/tarball/master -O - | tar xz
```

Even on Windows, you can do it, with the unix-like commands from [GoW (Gnu On Windows)](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki).

That would allow you then to add that new directory as one of your own.

Note: a submodule would be preferable, but isn't what you specifically asked.

---

The OP Steven Lu adds in the comments:

> I guess this works for Github, but what would you do if the repo wasn't hosted by Github?

For any other repo, you can use the command **`git archive --remote`**, as illustrated in "[`git archive` command with bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071070/git-archive-command-with-bitbucket/12073669#12073669)":

For instance:

```
git archive --remote=ssh://git@bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git --format=tar --output="file.tar" master
```

Comment: I guess this works for Github, but what would you do if the repo wasn't hosted by Github?

Comment: @StevenLu `git archive --remote`: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071070/git-archive-command-with-bitbucket/12073669#12073669

Comment: @StevenLu I have included the alternative solution in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score -1):

How do I do a quick clone without history revisions?

```
git clone --depth 1 your_repo_url
```

source : https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#How_do_I_do_a_quick_clone_without_history_revisions.3F

Comment: I can't be sure but I think there is no git way without .git @VonC pointed that you can download archive in github way.