# git archive from a specific hash from remote

Tags: git, hash, bitbucket, commit, archive

I am trying to get one directory from one remote repository but I only want to get that file from a specific hash. If I use git archive with HEAD everything is OK but when I try with a specific hash:

**git archive -v --format tar --remote=ssh://....myrepo.git agithash afile > output.tgz**

But I'm getting

```
fatal: sent error to the client: git upload-archive: archiver died with error
remote: fatal: no such ref: 9a9c309
remote: git upload-archive: archiver died with error
```

So I've read that I could use another upload-archive like this:

git archive -v --format tar --remote=ssh:.....myrepo.git --exec="/usr/local/bin/git upload-archive" ahash afile > output.tgz

It didn't work either. I assume is because BitBucket does not support it as per https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-upload-archive-archiver-died-with-error-779171761.html

So I wonder: is there another simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If that commit is referenced by a branch, You could do a shallow clone directly at the right commit:

```
git clone <url> --depth=1 --branch <branch_name> -- <folder_name>
```

And then make an archive.

But you cannot [directly get or clone a specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26135822/6309), for security reason.